# I want to access my environment variable before starting server in Next.js. How to do that?

Tags: node.js, next.js, hashicorp-vault, vault

I am using **vault** services to keep my secrets secure. For that, I need to run the vault script (node fetch-vault-secrets.js) before the next build and next dev command.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmH5P.png)
That vault command runs a file that contains a VAULT_SECRET_ID and ROLE_ID.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py72k.png)
I am accessing these secrets through the .env file but these secrets are not fetched before starting the server.
How I can solve the problem?

Comment: Please post any relevant code as a snippet, do _not_ use images for code.

Answer (score 0):

The doc on fs.writeFile is `Asynchronously writes data to a file`.

If you want the process to wait for the file to be written (ie, perform the work synchronously), try fs.writeFileSync.

Comment: The problem is it is not fetching the secrets from the .env file that I used to log in to the vault account.

Comment: fs.writeFile is working fine. The problem is I need to read the secret file from the vault and then write it. For reading the secret file I need vault credentials that I stored in the .env file that are not fetched. Hope you understand

Comment: No. You will have to show the code your using (not in a screenshot), the error you are getting, and what you expect to happen.